# Showing scraped information in pairs

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website for stock information.  It should show me the 'size' followed by the 'quantity' available.

```
element_size_name = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('itemSize')
element_qty_name = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('quantity')
for e in element_size_name:
    print(e.text)
for q in element_qty_name:
    print(q.text)
```

The above code gives me the following output:

```
>XL
>2XL
>5 Backorderable (Available: 06/02/2020)
>0 Backorderable (Available: 06/09/2020)
```

How can I put the first line '5 Backorderable (Available: 06/02/2020)' next to the XL and so on.
I've tried so many different things that give me totally different outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try builtin `zip()` function:

```
element_size_name = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('itemSize')
element_qty_name = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('quantity')

for e, q in zip(element_size_name, element_qty_name):
    print(e.text, q.text)
```

---

Test with "hard-coded" values:

```
element_size_name = ['XL', '2XL']
element_qty_name = ['5 Backorderable (Available: 06/02/2020)', '0 Backorderable (Available: 06/09/2020)']

for e, q in zip(element_size_name, element_qty_name):
    print(e, q)
```

Prints:

```
XL 5 Backorderable (Available: 06/02/2020)
2XL 0 Backorderable (Available: 06/09/2020)
```

Comment: Good answer with an example.